# Target file "ios" not found

Tags: flutter, apple-m1

Hi Im trying to run flutter app in Mac M1 , I ran `flutter run ios --verbose` I'm  getting this error log .
I deleted pod file and reinstall it none of worked for me .

```
.....
[  +58 ms] "flutter run" took 5,039ms.
[  +44 ms] Target file "ios" not found.
[   +5 ms] 
           #0      FlutterCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1404:9)
           #1      RunCommand.validateCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:456:19)
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1232:11)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1125:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:288:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:236:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:92:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           
           
[+1107 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 255ms
[   +1 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[        ] Shutdown hooks complete
[        ] exiting with code 1
```

How to mitigate this?.

Answer (score 5):

`flutter run ios` is not a valid command, if you trying to build then use
`flutter build ios --verbose`.

or just run `flutter run --verbose` which will generate pod file.